# VTK Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, linker-errors, vtk

I installed VTK 7.1.1 as suggested [here](https://thilinasameera.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/setting-up-vtk-and-itk-environments-for-ubuntu/).

I'm working on a new project with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vtk-7.1/vtkImageData.h>
#include <vtk-7.1/vtkMetaImageReader.h>
#include <vtk-7.1/vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtk-7.1/vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtk-7.1/vtkImageActor.h>
#include <vtk-7.1/vtkImageMapper3D.h>
#include <vtk-7.1/vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtk-7.1/vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>

int main()
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader> reader =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName("Test.mhd");
    reader->Update();
    std::cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

I am using the following to compile:

```
g++ -g -Wall -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -o main main.cpp
```

However, I keep getting errors such as the following:

```
/usr/local/include/vtk-7.1/vtkSmartPointer.h:29: error: undefined reference to `vtkSmartPointerBase::~vtkSmartPointerBase()'
```

Any idea as to why? I think it might be the linking maybe?

Comment: ***I think it might be the linking maybe?*** Yes, you don't seem to be linking to the vtk libraries. With that said its better to have CMake generate your MakeFile for your VTK based projects.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct the linker command is missing the required VTK libraries. Look in the following link for more details [VTK in Makefiles](https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtkusers/2012-March/073283.html).

For instance

`g++ -g -Wall -I /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lvtkCommon
 -lvtkFiltering -lvtkImaging -lvtkGraphics -lvtkGenericFiltering -lvtkIO
 -lvtkRendering -lvtkVolumeRendering`

To ease building your VTK applications you could use CMake

Comment: I think using CMake would make life simpler, since the writing all the libraries is quite cumbersome (especially since they are appended by the version). Thanks!